# Unity Ubuntu 14.04 very slow after login

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

When I first login after rebooting the computer, unity takes 10 min to show up the unity bar. After that when I just logout and login, it's much faster. How to fix this problem?

I already turned off most startup applications. The only apps available are:

```
Certificate and Key Storage
Dropbox
Files
GPG Password Agent
GSettings Data Conversion
Mount helper
Network
Nvidia X Server Settings
Onboard
PolicyKit Authentication Agent
SSH Key Agent
User folders update
```

Comment: Have you tried the latest 15.04 version?

Answer (score 1):

Use utilities such as `top` and `iotop` from the tty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to determine if a particular process is using all the CPU, disk, or other resource.

Comment: The top process during login are dropbox, rcuos and gvfsd-trash. But I think they all run concurrently (Unity bar should show up first and those process can run later). Is there a bug with Unity?

Comment: Are they using significant CPU?

Comment: No, max is 2% and memory is 3-4% as well

Comment: @Steven ,  Last I checked, Dropbox uses "nice" time, while being CPU and IO aggressive, so it may not appear on standard metrics.  A number of things use "background" time of one sort or another and thus bypass standard metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a fresh install or an upgrade? In either case (but more frequently in the latter) old/incomplete configurations can slow down your system greatly (other people would talk of *complete freeze* of Unity on boot, the 10-minutes time lapse is indeed quite trying for anyone's patience).

In your shoes, I would try a reinstall:

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 apt-get install unity
 apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
 shutdown -h now
```

Then, after the new bootup, you may reinstall the NVidia drivers.

Comment: It's definitely Unity, as I used Gnome and OpenBox and they show up immediately. There might be a bug of Unity not compatible with Nvidia drivers, as I am using CUDA.